# HTML Validation API returns an empty object in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, validation, firefox, constraint-validation-api

The validity property of an HTML input does not seem to work in Firefox.

```
var input = $input.get(0);
console.log(input.validity)
```

This console log returns an empty object. It's working on Chrome and Safari and I think it's also suppose to work on Firefox if I look at that doc?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

Any ideas?

Comment: it's a jQuery input element that I get from a function. $input.get(0) is to get the html element and not the jquery element.

Comment: I tried to [reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/Mp8f9/) your problem, but could not. Try including the minimum test case required to **fully** reproduce the issue.

Comment: If you try an [individual property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState), such as `input.validity.valid`, does it log a value?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Oh that works! I don't understand why though ^^. Why does validity return an empty object?

Comment: @Maxwell Firefox is likely only rendering [`enumerable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) properties (i.e. those that would appear in a `for..in` loop) while each of the `ValidityState`'s properties are probably `enumerable: false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's appearing as an empty object, it's likely because only [`enumerable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) properties are being rendered, which [`ValidityState`'s properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) don't seem to be in Firefox.

But, you should still be able to access individual properties:

```
console.log(input.validity.valid);   // true/false
console.log(input.validity.tooLong); // true/false
// etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

`input.validity` returns a special object, not just a simple boolean.

So, use `input.validity.valid` to check if an inputted value is correct.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/HdDfv/3/) to see validity properties.

And this [MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) about the ValidityState object.

And as far as debugging in Firefox, [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) shows this kind of stuff.